# Posted data is missing

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Im am migrating from IIS6 to IIS7 (integrated mode).
I had many issues but now almost everything is working exept this :
When I post data on urls like "/" or "/test/", Default.aspx is displayed but the posted data is missing on the HttpRequest object. 
There is no problem if I post to "/Default.aspx" or "/test/Default.aspx".
There is no problem either on my other server (IIS7 too) or my local server (IIS8). I tried to compare the handler config on both servers but did not found any difference.

Here is my test page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="text"/>
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="button"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            method: <%=Request.HttpMethod %>
            <br/>
            post: <%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form.ToString()) %>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you in postback scenarios, /test/ posbacking to /test/default.aspx ?  or pages posting to other pages ?

Comment: My test page is as simple a possible. No runat=server control, just a text input and a submit button.

Comment: And Request.Form["textinputname"] has no value ? please post your simple html page ( input should have id AND name attribute)

Comment: @jbl I edited my post to add my test page. It is working ok on my local IIS8 and beta server. It fails only on my production server with some urls.

Comment: @TomEsterez did you find out?

Comment: nope :( I edited the applicationHost.config file to make it very close of my beta server one but still have the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems migrating old sites from IIS6 to IIS7 and I'm quite sure this is a web.config problem.

The fastest way to figure it out is to set

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
```

It will throw exception until you have a valid web.config for integrated mode.

Many times there are config values valid for IIS6 not migrated to IIS7 and hidden

double check modules and handlers definitions they must be in different places:

in IIS6 they are into `<system.web>` element

in IIS7 they are into `<system.webServer>` element

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the validation tag but I have no error.

Comment: @TomEsterez check if all modules and handlers from iis6 are loaded in iis7

Comment: @TomEsterez just check that each module and handler definition in the web.config of iis6 are in the new web.config

Comment: My beta server is IIS7 too. I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: @TomEsterez it is not clear: are you posting from page A to page B? or just posting to self?

Comment: @TomEsterez try to debug with fiddler